# Economic Analysis / Minimization Problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, economics

I am studying and going through some old exams for a microeconomic analysis class. I am just looking for some clarification regarding one of the answers given. The question is as follows

> Suppose that a firm's production function is given by $y=lnx_{1}+2lnx_{2}$ where $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are respectively the amounts of input 1 and input 2, and $y$ is the output. Let $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ be the prices for inputs 1 and 2. Calculate the cost function for this firm.

I know that the cost function is given by

> $c(\mathbf{w}, y)=\min\; \;  w_{1}x_{1}+w_{2}x_{2}$
>
> such that $y=f(\mathbf{x})$

In this case it will be

> $c(w_{1},w_{2}, y)=\min\; \;  w_{1}x_{1}+w_{2}x_{2}$
>
> such that $y=f(x_1,x_2)=\ln x_{1}+2\ln x_{2}$

I set up the Lagrangian:

> $L=w_{1}x_{1}+w_{2}x_{2}+\lambda (y-\ln x_{1}+2\ln x_{2}) $

Solving for the first order conditions:

> $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=w_1 - \frac {\lambda }{x_1}=0$$
> $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=w_2 - \frac {2\lambda }{x_2}=0$$
> $$w_1 = \frac {\lambda }{x_1}$$
> $$w_2 = \frac {2\lambda }{x_2}$$

From here I divide $w_1$ by $w_2$ to find

> $$x_2=\frac {2x_1w_1}{w_2}$$
> $$x_1=\frac {w_2x_2}{2w_1}$$

I am okay up until this point. In the given answer the professor substitutes $x_2$ into the production function, so that

> $$y=\ln x_1+2\ln{(\frac{2x_1w_1}{w_2})}$$

From here he finds (after substituting in $x_1$ as well)

> $$x_1=\left ( \frac{e^yw_{2}^{2}}{4w_{1}^{2}} \right )^{1/3}$$
> and
> $$x_2=\left ( \frac{e^y2w_{1}}{w_{2}} \right )^{1/3}$$

I am having trouble arriving at the same thing. If anyone could show me his steps I would very much appreciate it. I wont show the different things I tried, but I of course started with $e^y=...$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are any of these steps difficult?

$$y=\ln x_1+2\ln{\left(\frac{2x_1w_1}{w_2}\right)}$$

$$y=\ln x_1+2\ln x_1 +2 \ln{\left(\frac{2w_1}{w_2}\right)}$$

$$3\ln x_1 = y- 2 \ln{\left(\frac{2w_1}{w_2}\right)}$$

$$\ln x_1 = \frac{1}{3} \left(y- {2} \ln{\left(\frac{2w_1}{w_2}\right)}\right)$$

$$ x_1 =  \left(\exp(y){\left(\frac{2w_1}{w_2}\right)^{-2}}\right)^\frac{1}{3}$$

$$ x_1 =  {\left(\frac{e^y w_2^2}{4w_1^2}\right)}^\frac{1}{3}$$